# I need a conditioning circuit for audio signal for input of microcontroller 3Vdd power supply and voltage reference?

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, audio

what is the Best circuit to amplify and condition a audio signal from a microphone to microcontroller analog input ?

Comment: "Best" means different things to different people. You need to do some research on your own and ask a specific question.

Comment: This site is not a free design service. If you want assistance with design, show us what you have done so far, what you are attempting to do, and why you are struggling. If you have done an insufficient amount yourself, your question is likely to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this useful

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmP8TW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>